# Adding Days to Date Type Field PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I have a date type field and I need to add 7 days to it.

If I was to use mySQL I'd be looking at something like:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DRAWING_COMPLETION_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

However, I need to translate this to PostgreSQL. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DRAWING_COMPLETION_DATE +  INTERVAL '7' DAY
from the_table;
```

alternatively, because the default unit is days for date arithmetics:

```
SELECT DRAWING_COMPLETION_DATE +  7
from the_table;
```